# Universal method for put y label at middle of y axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, axis

As the title suggests, I would like to know if there is a "universal" method to position the label of the ordinate axis horizontally to its left and vertically to its center.
In other words, place the label where "Here" is written (added through photo editing)

[image]

This is the original code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            legend pos=outer north east,
            legend cell align={left},
            grid, grid style=dashed,
            ymin=5,ymax=26,
            ytick={10,15,20,25},
            xtick={30,60,90,120,150},
            extra y ticks={5},            % <---
            xmax=180,xmin=0,
            extra x ticks={0},            % <---
            axis lines = middle,
            set layers,                   % <---
            x label style={at={(1,0)},right},  
            x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,
                fixed relative,
            },
            xlabel={$t$ (\unit{\min})},ylabel={$X$(\%)}, 
            style={thick}
        ]  
        \addplot[
            domain = 10:150,
            samples = 200,
            smooth,
            thick,
            verde,
        ]
        {-0.000626382144*x^2+0.237470377288*x+3.475363466567};
        \addlegendentry{\textit{p}-cresolo};
                                    
        \addplot[mark=*,scatter,only marks]
        coordinates {
            (10,6.01) (30,9.74) (60,15.78) (90,18.71) (120,24.29) (150,24.49)
        };
    \end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=0, xmax=1,
ymin=0, ymax=1,
ylabel={Here},
y label style={rotate=-90, at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)}, font=\Huge},
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with huge y label]

You can also use `(axis description cs:-0.1,0.5)` or `(yticklabel cs:0.5)` or `(yticklabel* cs:0.5, 20pt)` - dependent on exactly how you want to align the label.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code (partial...):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3]
    \draw[gray!10] (-1,-1) grid (10,10);
    \draw[line width=1pt,-latex] (-1,0)--(10,0) node[pos=.9,yshift=-12pt] () {\tiny \bfseries $Time$};
    
     \draw[line width=1pt,-latex] (0,-1)--(0,10) node[magenta,pos=.5,xshift=-20pt] () {\tiny \bfseries $Space$};
    \foreach \i in {1,2,...,10}{%
        \draw (\i,.1)--(\i,-.1) node[below] () {\tiny \i};
        \draw (.1,\i)--(-.1,\i) node[left] () {\tiny \i};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]